Difference between lstrip and removeprefix?
Why is removeprefix needed to remove a prefix from a string  (or text[text.startswith(prefix) and len(prefix):] for Python < 3.9, see Remove a prefix from a string), when it seems we can simply use lstrip?
Indeed:
"abchello".removeprefix("abc")   # hello
"abchello".lstrip("abc")         # hello


Try both of your examples with the string "cbahello" and you'll see.

@Matthias this was a self-answered question, I'm assuming OP chose that example deliberately...

@Matthias this is precisely the point.

Oh, I didn't check the author of the answer. On the other hand this is well documented at https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip.

Note: I have used the feature "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style".

lstrip takes a parameter which is a set of characters to be removed:
  'www.example.com'.lstrip('cmowz.')  # example.com

Corollary: it can remove multiple times the leading characters, example:
  "abcbaaaaachello".lstrip("abc")           # hello
  "abcbaaaaachello".removeprefix("abc")     # baaaaachello


Perhaps worth mentioning that str.lstrip() with no argument will remove any/all leading whitespace

@SIGHUP Good idea, feel free to edit to mention it!
